# "No query defined for that name" exception occurs when using spring-data-jpa without "@Query"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring-data-jpa with hibernate and mysql.

I have the following entity

```java
package com.wayne.domain.player;
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLAYER")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    // ...
}
```

and repository:

```java
@Repository
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, Long> {
    List<Player> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

when I build and run the project, I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name [Player.findByEmail]
```

but findByEmail method works fine.

If I modify the method with "@Query" annotation like this:

```
@Repository
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, Long> {
    @Query("select p from Player p where p.email = ?1")
    List<Player> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

there is no exception, and findByEmail method works fine.

I know that spring-data-jpa automatically creates queries from method names.
But why is there an exception without "@Query" annotation?

Comment: Maybe `findByEMAIL`?

Comment: @jun, were you able to find a solution to this problem that did not involve using `@Query`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might just be a minor bug in the Spring Data module with how the code handles the default setting for *Query Lookup Strategies* or perhaps you've tweaked the strategy in the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation.

Either way, the documentation says the default is `CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND` which combines both `CREATE` and `USE_DECLARED_QUERY`.  First it looks for a declared `@NamedQuery` based on the method name specified and if not found, delegates to create a new one on the fly.

I wonder (I haven't looked at the code directly) if the exception is thrown, logged, and caught as part of the logic to know to delegate to the `CREATE` option when `USE_DECLARED_QUERY` failed based on the default setting Spring data uses.

The reason introducing the `@Query` annotation resolves this is because that alters the strategy behavior to only use `CREATE` and so a named-query is generated with the value of `@Query`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a no args constructor or use the annotation for Lombok so that it generates one for you. Make sure that Lombok is working as expected, I had issues with it trying to get it to work with STS.